# Same LiDAR data but different results in ArcMap and eCognition

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcmap, lidar, ecognition

I have generated raster layers based on LiDAR Number of Returns in both ArcMap and eCognition but the results are quite different.

I ArcMap I used *LAS point to Statistics to Raster Tool*, in the option *Method* I chose POINT_COUNT and the output was shown as below
[image]

[image]

However, when I did the same thing in eCognition I got a different output
[image]
[image]

I must have made some mistakes in ArcMap as the value of the generated raster layer varies from 1 to 1573

[image]

Which tool in ArcMap I should use so I can generate a raster layer based on LiDAR Number of Returns?

Comment: Are you sure you your projections for both the same ?

Comment: I don't use eCognition or Arcgis but it seems that in the first case you are counting the # of points per cell and in the second case you are evaluating the maximum number of returns (field = number of returns, operation = maximum). This makes sense with the picture: 1 return in asphalt, many in trees.

Comment: @JRR I think you should write that as an answer.